# Randomize array of objects which contains specific key->value

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array with 45 object elements containing `id`, `name`, `is_premium`.

From MySQL I receive them, ordered by `is_premium desc`, and some of them have `is_premium = 0` at the end of list.

How can I randomize elements with `is_premium=1`, keeping the `is_premium=0` at the end of array?

Comment: Did you try writing any code for this?

Comment: Yes, by splitting premium=1 ones in a different array, unset them, randomize then merge with is_premium=0, but this method is overloading my server on 20 requests / second. (my original array is bigger)

Comment: Are you looking for suggestion on how to better query the data to get it in the order you want?  Perhaps some code examples would help here.

Comment: what programming language? (better not try this in SQL)

Comment: Just determine where the first and last items are for is_premium = 1, then shuffle that part of the array. There is no need to move them to another array and back again.

Comment: @AgapieAurel you could try two things. Try building a cache index for requests and try using pthreads to execute your randomizing code asynchronously. This should help you with the overloading problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works:

```
<?php 
//assuming the array of objects is called $array
$new_array = array_merge(
    shuffle(
        array_filter($array,function($x){return $x['is_premium'] == 1;})
    ),
    array_filter($array,function($x){return $x['is_premium'] == 0;})
);
?>
```

Comment: Worked with a small edit, because shuffle() returns bool